# export 'actionTypes' (imported as 'actionTypes') was not found in './pages.actionTypes'

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I am building a React app that uses Redux-Thunks. I am receiving an error message and cannot figure out how to resolve it. I am new to using Redux-Thunks and have been using [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a6uC2EauAZ4&t=56s&ab_channel=TutorialsTeam) tutorial to set up . I checked all my dependencies and files to ensure I did as instructed but still I have been unable to resolve this bug.

The error message is:

pages.thunks.js

```
export 'default' (imported as 'actions') was not found in './pages.actions' (possible exports: pagesLoadError, pagesLoadStart, pagesLoadSuccess)
```

Although page.thunks.js is receiving error messages I believe the issue is coming from pages.actionTypes.js and pages.initialState.js

pages.actionTypes.js

```
export default  {    
   PAGES_LOAD_START: "PAGES_LOAD_START",
    PAGES_LOAD_SUCCESS: "PAGES_LOAD_SUCCESS",
    PAGES_LOAD_ERROR: "PAGES_LOAD_ERROR",
}
```

pages.initialState.js

```
export default {
    isLoading: false,
    pages: null,
    errorMessage: null,
};
```

pages.thunks.js

```
import PagesServices from '../../../services/pages.services.js';
import actions from './pages.actions';

export const loadPagesAsync = () => (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(actions.pagesLoadStart())

    PagesServices.getAllPages()
        .then(response => dispatch(actions.pagesLoadSuccess(response.data)))
        .catch(error => dispatch(actions.pagesLoadError(error.message)))
}
```

pages.actions.js

```
import actionTypes from './pages.actionTypes'

export const pagesLoadStart = () => ({
    type: actionTypes.PAGES_LOAD_START,
})

export const pagesLoadSuccess = pages => ({
    type: actionTypes.PAGES_LOAD_SUCCESS,
    payload: pages
})

export const pagesLoadError = errorMessage => ({
    type: actionTypes.PAGES_LOAD_ERROR,
    payload: errorMessage
})
```

Comment: Just as you seem to be learning Redux right now, please be aware that you are generally learning a very outdated style of Redux. Modern Redux does not use switch..case reducers, ACTION_TYPEs, immutable reducer logic, createStore or connect/mapStateToProps and is generally more failsafe and only 1/4 of the code. Please follow the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting `pagesLoadStart`, `pagesLoadSuccess` and `pagesLoadError` from pages.actions.js yet you are trying to import `actions` from it. That isn't going to work - there is no actions object exported by pages.actions.js

To fix, change the second line of pages.thunks.js to:

```
import * as actions from './pages.actions';
```

The rest of your code should work fine, though you may only want to import specific functions.